# How to sequentialize user events that cause some heavy asynchronous processing

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, event-handling

I'm looking for a pattern on how to solve a typical problem when multiple (user) events are triggered shortly after each other and each event must take care of some heavy load that must be processed to its end before a new event can be accepted.

A typical use case would for example be a list of items the user can click on and for each item some asynchronous loading and processing is required.
A user would click on an item that will trigger the asynchronous processing.
While an event is processed no new processing should be started when another item is selected and in the best case (performance) only the last event would need to be processed.

The following code snipped simulates the use case and the console output shows how the event are issues and then processed.
The function `run` simulates the (user) events and the function `heavyLifting` simulates some asynchronous heavy lifting.
More events than needed are processed and by making sure that the `heavyLifting` function is only invoked sequentially using the `currentlyLifting` semaphore it is also no longer guaranteed that at least the very last event is always processed.

**Use [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d4p8057c/5/) to run the code snipped**

```js
const getRandom = (min, max) => Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);

const heavyLifting = id => {
return new Promise(resolve => {
 const cost = getRandom(500, 750)
 console.log(`heavy lifting "${id}" with cost "${cost}" started...`);
 setTimeout(() => {
  console.log(`heavy lifting "${id}" completed.`);
  resolve();
 }, cost);
});
};

let currentlyLifting;
window.addEventListener('heavyLift', async (e) => {
const id = e.detail.id;
if (currentlyLifting !== undefined) {
 console.log(`cannot start new heavy lifting of "${id}" while still running "${currentlyLifting}"`);
} else {
 currentlyLifting = id;
 await heavyLifting(id);
 currentlyLifting = undefined;
}
});

const run = () => {
let id = 1;
const timerCallback = () => {
 console.log(`dispatchEvent "${id}"`);
 window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('heavyLift', {detail: {id}}));
 if (id++ < 10) {
  setTimeout(timerCallback, 100);
 }
};
timerCallback();
};

run();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <body>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just remember the last event, and after the `await heavyLifting(id);` check whether the last event is the one you just processed or whether there is a new one to get processed.

Comment: @Bergi This is intuitively a possible pattern but I don’t see a way to then prevent additional events to arrive while processing the new one. Do you have a working example of your approach?

Comment: You don't need to prevent them from arriving, you just need them to not start processing.

Comment: I agree, but how would you do that based on my code snipped? I guess you would keep the semaphore in the event handler but additionally keep track of the last event that must be processed and after `await heavyLifting(id);` finishes, process the potentially last missing event. How can you prevent that in while processing this one no others arrive and we are back to square one?

Comment: Yes, keep the semaphore. You prevent processing newly arriving ones like you already do, with `if (currentlyLifting !== undefined)`.

Comment: I still do not understand how you would implement this? Let's use my example with 10 events and assume that the 9th was the last one completed but 10 got skipped. What code would you use to now process the 10th event and how would you prevent this to happen again while processing the 10th one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could await the previous processing promise before doing the next processing:

```
 const oneAtATime = () => {
   let previous = Promise.resolve();
   return action => previous = previous.then(action);
 };

const lifting = oneAtATime();

lifting(async function() {
 //...
});

 lifting(async function() {
  //...
 });
```

Or to wait for all currently actions to be done just

```
 await lifting(); // don't do that in a lifting task itself, that will cause a livelock
```

Comment: I understand your approach of serializing the asynchronous lifting of the heavy load but cannot seem to understand how this fits in my code snippet that receives individual events? Would you be so kind to show me how you would do this in my code snipped? I’m also not sure how this would reduce the number of events that must be lifted?

Comment: @boberkofler maybe I missunderstand your usecase: What happens if there is already an async action and a new one gets started? Should that wait? Or should it be cancelled?

Comment: In my use case I cannot start a new one while one is already running, so I can only skip the processing. The goal would be to skip as many as possible like with a debounce but make sure that the last event is always processed.

Comment: @doberkofler well then the code in the question is the way to go, not sure if I can help you further

Comment: My code snipped shows that it does not work as it should because by simply skipping the events it cannot be guaranteed, that always the last event is processed. I'm still looking for a solution to this problem.

Comment: @doberkofler sounds impossible. You won't know if a function will be called again in the future.

Comment: The events can be stored to a ring buffer that then will be processed in some other timer based loop. Sounds complicated but maybe that's the only way. I'm still surprised that this is not a quite common use case that people come along all the time.